# rails rspec code (/spec) from real world applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, rspec2

I am learning rspec for ruby on rails, v 3.1
I know that there are a number of styles to writing specs.
In addition to all the theory and books that I am studying...
can you point to any github public repo's that have a good quantity of quality rspec's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [Whois library](https://github.com/weppos/whois) counts 4254 example in more than 500 spec files. You can check the output of a spec run at [Travis CI page](http://travis-ci.org/#!/weppos/whois/builds/235207).

Comment: Awesome.  That gets a check! Thx!